# Bootstrap logo Not Aligning With Navbar on Mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

Here's a screenshot of my current navbar: https://i.gyazo.com/374a580912788822e83809aa1ed501d3.png

The logo is not aligning with the navbar collapse button.

Here's my bootstrap code:

```html
<!--Nav start-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg theme-nav fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
         <a href="index.html"><img src="../assets/images/logo9.svg" alt="logo"></a>
           <button style="margin-left:10%;" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fa fa-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="mymenu">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about" >How it Works</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#package" >Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#faq" >FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about" >How it Works</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link btn btn-success" href="sign-in.php" style="padding: 10px;margin-top: 12px;color: #fff;background-color: #4cd137;">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link btn btn-success" href="#package" style="padding: 10px;margin-top: 12px;color: #fff;background-color: #4cd137;">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!--Nav end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the button tag before the anchor tag and then end the div tag in order to align your brand with the collapse button. I hope this works for you